# Is there an equivalent to "$this" in Emmet plugin?

Tags: html, emmet

Hmm.. have not found an answer to this... so here goes.

- Want to create a form using Emmet syntax.
- I have the following list of items:

  ```
  firstName
  lastName
  middleInitial
  suffixName
  streetAddress1
  streetAddress2
  streetAddress3
  cityAddress
  stateAddress
  zipCodeAddress
  countryAddress
  phoneNumber1
  phoneNumber1Type
  phoneNumber2
  phoneNumber2Type
  dob
  gender
  maidenName
  ```
- I could use something like the following Emmet syntax to create a form:

  `form:get.newUserForm>input.formInput[name=FieldName]*`

(That may be slightly incorrect.. but that's not the focus of the question.)

The question is..

How can I get each "FieldName" to match the selected item in the list?   For example, the first item in my list is "firstName", and the second is "lastName".  Is there a way for Emmet to see the list item and use THAT in place of "FieldName" (or "id" for that matter)?  So in basic terms.. is there an equivalent to `$this` (referring to the item in the list) in Emmet?

TTAIA

Comment: Is that what you’re looking for? 
http://docs.emmet.io/actions/wrap-with-abbreviation/#controlling-output-position

Comment: Why yes it is.  Thanks for showing me something I had not found!

Comment: @SergeyChikuyonok How do I mark your comment as the answer?  I don't want to answer my own question and take credit for it, when you answered it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Emmet inserts wrapped content inside deepest child node of abbreviation, but you can decide where to put wrapped content with `$#` token.

E.g. you can write something like `form:get.newUserForm>input.formInput[name=$#]*` to insert strings into `name` attribute of `<input>` element.

See http://docs.emmet.io/actions/wrap-with-abbreviation/#controlling-output-position